# Error with JSON data ("Expected a JSON object, array or literal")

Tags: javascript, json

I'm following a JSON tutorial and I've run into a problem.

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I have an HTML file, a JS file, and a JSON file.  Even though the data in the JSON file is (to the best of my understanding) correctly formatted, VSCode gives me the following error:

> Expected a JSON object, array, or literal.

Right now, the JS file is empty.  The code in my HTML file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SANDBOX</h1>
    <div class="output">

    </div>
</body>
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

and the data in my .JSON file is:

```
const json = {
    "books": [{
        "title": "Learn to Code",
        "author": "John Smith",
        "isbn": "324-23243"
    }, {
        "title": "The Adventures JSON",
        "author": "Jason Jones",
        "isbn": "3324-2-444"
    }, {
        "title": "New Objects",
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "isbn": "2343-234-2433"
    }]
};
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Following the tutorial - The tutor doesn't seem to have this problem, for some reason.
2. Wrapping the JSON data in curly braces - This just throws three more errors: *Property keys must be doublequoted, Colon expected,* and *End of file expected.*
3. Searching this site for similar questions - I've found similar questions, but the solutions offered don't solve my problem.  I'm always left with the original error, 'Expected a JSON object, array or literal'.

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your file name is `.json` but the content is javascript. Try renaming it to `.js` or removing `const json =` (but not both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use javascript inside `.json` file

change `.json` file to

```
[{
        "title": "Learn to Code",
        "author": "John Smith",
        "isbn": "324-23243"
    }, {
        "title": "The Adventures JSON",
        "author": "Jason Jones",
        "isbn": "3324-2-444"
    }, {
        "title": "New Objects",
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "isbn": "2343-234-2433"
    }]
```

instead load your json file inside the `app.js`

```
const books = require("my.json")
```

BUT

if you wish to use it like that
then you have to change the format of `my.json` to `my.js`